# easier way to debug a NPM truffle project?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, geth-debugging

I'm using open zepplin to try to code these forks and contracts and i cant seem to get NPM to configure correctly.

## I have tried all of these types of things.

1. ****Uninstall* and global reinstall NPM and truffle.***

2. ****Debug,* but had no luck.***
3. ***searched* for related questions, on here and can't put my finger on it.**
4. *funded the packages,also read the log files.*

is there any quick `NPM i <example>`to try to trouble shoot the issue?

````
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from file-loader@4.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/file-loader
npm WARN   file-loader@"4.3.0" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   html-webpack-plugin@"4.0.0-beta.11" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.4.0" from mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN   mini-css-extract-plugin@"0.9.0" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.3
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@"5.0.3" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from url-loader@2.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/url-loader
npm WARN   url-loader@"2.3.0" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"2 || 3 || 4" from webpack-manifest-plugin@2.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin
npm WARN   webpack-manifest-plugin@"2.2.0" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: webpack@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from workbox-webpack-plugin@4.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   workbox-webpack-plugin@"4.3.1" from react-scripts@3.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts```
````

Comment: Hi there. How did you initialise this project?

Comment: hello ! nice to see a friendly person, truffle init was my start